# How to create a simple menu which works out of the application in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

How can I create a small menu which pop-ups next to cursor in WPF with C#. This menu will work out of the application window. For example;

I move my cursor and stop it on the desktop. When it stops, there will be a small menu which is just next to the cursor and show up.

Thanks

The CODE:

```
    static System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        big.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        myTimer.Stop();              
    }

    public void TimerEventProcessor2(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        big.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        myTimer.Stop();
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.
        myTimer.Interval = 5000;
        myTimer.Start();
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

        myTimer.Start(); 
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor2);
    }
```

EDIT2

This is the part of the code. I created another dispatchertimer whish has a name hidingtimer. I defined the time as 3 seconds as you see on the code. And this timer calls deneme_Tick then I do the same things as HideWindow() in your code.

```
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        timer.Tick += (sd, args) =>
        {
            movingCount++;

            if (movingCount >= menuShowDelay)
            {
                this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                mouse.Enabled = false;
                timer.Stop();
                this.Left = mouseLeft;
                this.Top = mouseTop;
                this.Topmost = true;

                hidingtimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3);
                hidingtimer.Start();
                hidingtimer.Tick += new EventHandler(deneme_Tick);

                movingCount = 0;
            }



        };
```

Comment: Are you wanting to drag something from the application and paste it on the desktop? Otherwise please clarify your requirements. Moving the cursor and clicking somewhere else will give the control underneath the focus, so what you are asking and why you want to do this is not exactly clear.

Comment: When I run the application and after 1 second the application started, I want a menu to appear just near the cursor. This menu will appear whereever the cursor is on the desktop. This is all what I want. Thank you.

Comment: one of your problems of EDIT 2 is the line `hidingtimer.Tick += new EventHandler(deneme_Tick);` - with this you are adding the event handler EVERY time timer.Tick happens. So when hidingtimer.Tick happens, it will execute n times. An easier way is just use the same timer and create another variable to control when to show the window - I update the project on github to do that: https://github.com/leo-mck/WPFMouseMenu

Comment: This is very nice solution.Thanks again. So, you say that If I want to use another timing tasks, I will use the same timer with different variables.I will consider this, thank you. Because I will have to use many timers in this project. This was one of them. It helped so much.

In my idea, I was trying to connect hiding the window part to the mouse movement. For example; we moved the cursor and stoped.then menu is opened. we didnt move the mouse and menu is hided. It won't be open again until the next movement happened and stoped.

Otherwise if the curser is stable,it will popup every 3sec.

Comment: In this case it was easier to just use one timer but you sure can use as many as you want to other tasks... but it is easy to make things  complex when you have many timers running simultaneously. To not show the menu again if there was no movement you can maybe compare if the mouseLeft and mouseTop variable has not changed since last time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

This is how I would do it:

- Create your menu in WPF any way you want (it could be a real menu or a listbox, buttons on a stackpanel, etc).
- Set your WindowStyle to None.
- To detect mouse movement and position you could use [this library](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/)
- Write some logic to show/hide the window on the mouse position (with a timer to detect when the mouse isn't moving for X seconds)

If you need more details on how to acomplish those steps, let me know :)

**EDIT 1**

You can use the library to detect mouse movement like this:

```
mouse = new MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.MouseHookListener(new GlobalHooker());
mouse.MouseMove += (sd, args) =>
        {
            movingCount = 0;
            mouseLeft = args.X; //set the window.left to mouseLeft before showing it
            mouseTop = args.Y; //set the window.top to mouseTop before showing it
        };

mouse.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: All the things are ok except last step... this is the problem I can not do. How will I show and hide the window? Is there any command to show and hide for main window?

Comment: Sure, you can hide the window setting its `Visibility` property to `Hidden` or `Collapsed`

Comment: Ok, I got this one and worked...but won't this hide and show the window at its current location? How will say that " ok, appear at this specific location".

Comment: are you using the library i suggested to detect mouse movement? If yes, on the mouseMove event you can get and save the cursor X and Y positions to variables so before you show the window you set the `Left` and `Top`

Comment: i will try it after I solve the timing problem:) Can you look at this please. Where do I do the wrong? This mainwindow name is big in the code. So I want to show it 5 sec. and hide it for 5 sec. this will keep going like this. But when I run the code, I show it for 5 sec. but I hides and shows up immediately. the code is up in my question.

Comment: There is some problems, you are calling Start 2 times with 2 different handlers and I recomend you to use the DispatcherTimer... look [here](https://github.com/leo-mck/WPFMouseMenu), I created a basic project that does what you want :)

Comment: :) this was perfect...thanks a lot...:) what exactly I wanted. but I try to understand where is my mistake...I will solve it...Thank you again...

Comment: If it helped, mark as the right answer/upvote so it could help others too ;)

Comment: I have one question. How Do I start another timer if the timer already started. In your code, after 5 seconds pass, menu shows up. If I dont move the cursor after menu shows up, lets say 3 seconds passed, I want it to be collapsed again. but if I use  timer.Tick += (sd, args) => one more under  timer.Tick += (sd, args) => , it gives an error. What is the usage of it? Thank you

Comment: ok Leo, actually I did something, but this wasnt what I wanted. Can you check the code above please. EDIT2.  If I do this,It collapses the menu window all the time.What I wanted is to collapse it 3 seconds after menu shows up. But If the mouse doesnt move. If it moves, it will not collapse it. Thanks...

Comment: This is very nice solution.Thanks again. So, you say that If I want to use another timing tasks, I will use the same timer with different variables.I will consider this, thank you. Because I will have to use many timers in this project. This was one of them. It helped so much. In my idea, I was trying to connect hiding the window part to the mouse movement. For example; we moved the cursor and stoped.then menu is opened. we didnt move the mouse and menu is hided. It won't be open again until the next movement happened and stoped. Otherwise if the curser is stable,it will popup every 3sec

Comment: Hi Leo, I think I need your ideas. You know your solution worked and I developed it. There is one problem about this. Now, I control the cursor remotely. The problem is mouse position is never accurate.There is always some noise. I need to define some pixels which are considered mouse is stable. For example, When I stop the cursor, it doesnt stop, but it moves always a few pixel.So, Let's define 5 pixel, If mouse even moves 5 pixel, It will trigger the timer which you did before. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just have a crack, have a look here,

http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=92

If possible add a context menu to your main window, and then make it appear programatically like this,

[Show menu programmatically in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165562/show-menu-programmatically-in-wpf)

Use a timer to make it happen after 1 second.

Whether it will appear where the cursor is or not I am unsure.

Comment: But this idea is just working in the application window. I tried with the right click and it just does it in the application window. I need to do it out of the appliaction window...Do you have any idea?