# ContextMenuService.Placement on Button only works with right click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to pop up a context menu when the user LEFT clicks a button, and I want the menu to appear above the button.  When the user right clicks the button it should do the same thing.  Here is the XAML I use to try to do that:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Width="32" Height="32"  ContextMenuService.Placement="Top">
    <Image Source="/Images/config.png" Width="18" Height="18" Stretch="Fill" />
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Play Sounds" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding PlaySounds, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Always On Top" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding OnTop, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

I set a breakpoint on the "PlaySounds" get/set properties to make sure this is being respected...

When I RIGHT CLICK on the icon, everything works fine.  The context menu pops up above the button and the PlaySounds 'get' property is called.  However if I instead LEFT CLICK on the icon, the menu pops up where the icon was clicked...not above the button as it should, and the "PlaySounds" and "OnTop" get properties are not called...

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this so that LEFT click does the right thing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [wpf context menu left-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513315/wpf-context-menu-left-click)

Comment: Right click is expected behavior, see duplicate link for suggestion.